# How to get the MESH filenames from the urdf_parser?

Tags: urdf, mesh

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi, I am trying to retrieve the mesh file names/paths from the robot URDF description.  I seem to be able to get all of the other information (link name, mesh origin, parent/child link names, etc.).

Here is my code:

```
urdf::Model urdfModel;
if (!urdfModel.initParam("robot_description")) {
        ROS_ERROR("Error parsing URDF file...");
        return false;
}
string lnk_name = "/r2/left_palm";
boost::shared_ptr<urdf::Link> lnk;
urdfModel.getLink(lnk_name, lnk);

cout << "what is the type of model: " << viz->geometry->type << endl;
cout << viz->origin.position.x << endl;
cout << viz->origin.position.y << endl;
cout << viz->origin.position.z << endl;
```

That all works great, but I can't for the life of me figure out where the meshname is stored....

Thanks!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/43883/how-to-get-the-mesh-filenames-from-the-urdf_parser?/) by [shart115](https://answers.ros.org/users/1531/shart115/) on ROS Answers with karma: 86 on 2012-09-14

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I haven't tried this out, but in general, it's under collision or visual geometry:

```
boost::dynamic_pointer_cast<const urdf::Mesh>(link->collision->geometry)->filename
```

---

Originally posted by [hsu](https://answers.ros.org/users/91/hsu/) with karma: 5780 on 2012-09-14

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [shart115](https://answers.ros.org/users/1531/shart115/) on 2012-09-17**:
Awesome, that works perfect.  Thanks!

**Comment by [mkopack](https://answers.ros.org/users/1024/mkopack/) on 2012-10-16**:
Could you guys please explain this a bit more. I'm utterly confused 1) how the example code in the quesiton could possibly work. Where is viz defined? 2) how this answer works... I don't get it at all. You're defining a dynamic pointer of type Mesh, but I don't get the rest...

**Comment by [mkopack](https://answers.ros.org/users/1024/mkopack/) on 2012-10-16**:
Also doesn't help that the documentation for the urdf stuff is horribly lacking and has circular references. The example code only shows how to load it to be parsed, doesn't show how to access any of the data.